# angular2 view not getting updated after array variable is changed

Tags: javascript, data-binding, typescript, angular

I am working on this angular2 project in which I have a DemoComponent which accepts input as an array & is a child component of ExampleComponent:

```
@Component({
 selector:'demo',
 template:`
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of values;let i=index" (click)="deleteArrayItem(values,i)">
         {{item.name}}
      </li>
  </ul>
 `
})
export class DemoComponent{
    @Input('values') values:Array<any>;
    constructor(){
    }
    deleteArrayItem(data:Array<any>,index:number){
       data.splice(index,1);
       console.log(data);        
    }
}
```

Now, In parents template, I am passing array to this component as:

```
<demo [values]="items"></demo>
```

So far demo component loads array elements correctly in list.when I am deleting an element after clicking it, I can see value getting deleted in console.But its not getting reflected in the UI.

It gets reflected in UI only after I collapse the DemoComponent and open it again.

I tried doing `<demo [(values)]="items"></demo>` but I got an error:

> Cannot assign to a reference or variable

PS. this demo component & ExampleComponent are loaded using dynamic component loader in angular2 like below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
let componentIndex = this.keysRegister.indexOf('ExampleComponent');
this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(this.typesRegister[componentIndex],
  this.target).then(ref => {
    this.componentRef = ref;      
    this.updateModel();
  });
console.log('Generic Component...ExampleComponent... Loaded");
}
updateModel() {
    if(!this.componentRef) return;
    this.componentRef.instance.componentModel = this.componentModel;
}
```

Comment: put the code in a fiddle and post the link

Comment: there you don't need to pass `values` in `deleteArrayItem`, its already there in controller, instead do like `this.values.splice(index,1);` Obviously this isn't answer.

Comment: @PankajParkar I tried that, still view is not getting updated after deletion

Comment: Maybe you are using `ChangeDetectionstrategy.OnPush` on some of your parent components?
I checked your code - for normal standalone app it works fine, the same code, as yours..

Comment: @OlegBarinov I havent used that.. but the component which is rendering the parent component of `demoComponent` is loaded using dynamic component loader.#rc1

Comment: @Ajey Sorry I cannot post the code as far now in fiddle ,But i have updated my question details.

Comment: emm.. DynamicComponentLoader is now deprecated, maybe you can try to do it with ComponentResolver (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentResolver-class.html) and check again?

Comment: @OlegBarinov I am on rc1 currently.& cant upgrade to rc4 as of now